# Dynamically formatting dates and times fetched from an API in iso format

Tags: python-3.x

I am fetching data from an API that comes in iso formated strings, for ex - example 2022-07-27T00:00:00.0000000+01:00

```
end_date=item['RunDate'] 
start_time=portion['StartTimeWTT']
```

I am trying to format the date to look like: yyyy-mm-dd and time hh:mm:ss
I have tried different solutions but none of them works

```
end_date1=item['RunDate']
end_date=datetime.date().strftime(end_date1,'%Y-%M-%d')

or datetime.fromisoformat
```

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the easiest way to handle date strings is by using the dateutil library.  For example in your cited case:

```
from dateutil import parser
from dateutil.utils import default_tzinfo
from dateutil.tz import tzoffset
tx = '2022-07-27T00:00:00.0000000+01:00'
tz_data = tzoffset("EST", 0)
print(default_tzinfo(parser.parse(tx) , tz_data))
```

yields

```
2022-07-27 00:00:00+01:00
```